# Decomposing a matrix $M$ in the form $M = P^{-1}QP$ where $Q$ and $P$ are real matrices and Q is as diagonal as possible

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form, block-matrices

I am currently working on a tiny matrix library in C++ to help myself learn more about them. So far, I have implemented basic functions such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, the determinant, cofactor, adjoint and inverse, and was recently looking into $\exp\left(M\right)$, $\ln\left(M\right)$, $\ln\left(M\right)$, $\ln\left(M\right)$, and other such functions.

I am currently only working on functions which are equal to their taylor series ($\exp\left(M\right)$, $\sin\left(M\right)$, $\cos\left(M\right)$, ...).

To implement the functions, one method would be to use the taylor series directly

$$\exp(M) = I + M + \frac{1}{2!}M + \frac{1}{3!}M + \frac{1}{4!}M + \frac{1}{5!}M\dots$$

Mathematically, this would work just fine so tried it, and it was bad, to say the least. Matrix multiplication is a very slow algorithm, and the series does not converge very fast.

## My Progress

---

After looking into it, I learned about diagonalization of matrices. Then, I learned that exponentiation of diagonal matrices is just that element to the power, and I thought I could use this to my advantage.

Let our function be $f(M)$ and let its taylor series be

$$f(M) = a_0I + a_1M + \frac{a_2}{2!}M + \frac{a_3}{3!}M + \frac{a_4}{4!}M + \frac{a_5}{5!}M\dots$$
We can write $f(M)$ compactly as
$$f(M) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty{\frac{a_i}{i!}M^i}$$

If $M$ is of the form $M = P^{-1}QP$, then

$$
f(M) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty{\frac{a_i}{i!}M^i}
\\~\\
f(M) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty{\frac{a_i}{i!}{P^{-1}}^iQ^iP^i}
\\~\\
f(M) = P^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty{\frac{a_i}{i!}Q^i}\right)P
\\~\\
f(M) = P^{-1}\left[\sum_{i=0}^\infty{\frac{a_i}{i!}q^i}\right]P
\\~\\
f(M) = P^{-1}\left[f(q)\right]P
$$
If $q$ denotes the diagonal elements.

I quickly ran into a problem, not every matrix can be diagonalized. I discovered the Jordan Normal Form, and a similar result can be proved for the Jordan Normal Form by exponentiating blocks instead of diagonal elements.

With the JNF, I ran into the problem that matrices can have complex eigenvalues, and I haven't been able to find any solution to it.

## My Problem

---

I want to be able to take any matrix $M$ and write it in the form
$$M = P^{-1}QP$$
where

- P is an invertible matrix
- Q is a matrix such that Q is a diagonal block matrix.
- Q has as few blocks larger than $1\times1$ as possible.
- Q has only real elements (Otherwise the JNF would have sufficed)

Comment: If the Jordan form has $1×1$ block of a complex eigenvalue then there is no way you can get a $1×1$ real block to replace that. Best you can do is combine two complex blocks corresponding to conjugates to get a real block. So the size will double in this process. All and all it doesn't look very efficient. There should be more effecient methods to simply multiply complex numbers, or there aren't?

Comment: @TonySmith I am working with real matrices so my jordan blocks are in complementary pairs.
Could you explain what you mean by combining jordan blocks, preferably with a link to an article?

Comment: What I mean is this: suppose you have a $1×1$ jordan block corresponding to eigenvalue $z$ then you have one for $\bar z$. Together they will give you a $2×2$ diagonal matrix with complex entries. Now you can change the basis and turn this block into a real block. Similarly you can combine two $n×n$ blocks to make one real $2n × 2n$ block. But you can't get any real blocks smaller than that on the diagonal. There is no paper to refer to for this. You just have to learn basis, matrix representation, diagonalization stuff like that.

Comment: One natural way to get real block diagonal matrix is starting with some vector $u$ and taking as basis vectors $u, Au, A^2u, \ldots$ as far as they are linearly independent. Then starting with a different vector, and proceeding until you get complete basis. I don't remember what this form is called. The block you obtain this way will have a pretty simple structure. Although I have no idea if that simplicity translates to simplicity in successive multiplication.